# Install Package with Pip on Google Datalab - No Space on Device

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I'm trying to install the package sodapy using Pip on a fresh instance of Google Datalab but I'm receiving the error 'No space left on device.'  I created this instance with over 100 GB of disk space so I'm a bit confused why I would be getting this error and I've tried deleting instances and creating new ones with no luck.

[image]

I'm using the command

```
!pip install sodapy
```

as is explained in the documentation- https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have run into a bug where the Disk was not being attached: https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1898

(If that is the case, reseting the VM once should fix it and you should update to gcloud version 186.0.0 or later.)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `--user` flag to the pip install command. This switches to using your persistent disk, which is the 100GB disk, instead of your VM's boot disk for the installed package.